# Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::string does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

when trying to migrate I get the above error, i don't know what's the problem

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddLayerNameColumnToMapboxUploadsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('mapbox_uploads', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('layer_name')->nullable()->after('tileset_type');
            $table->string('file_name')->nullable()->after('layer_name');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('mapbox_uploads', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('layer_name');
            $table->dropColumn('file_name');
        });
    }
}
```

How to fix it? string is spelled correctly and I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: Hmm. This is weird. Try something else except ```string``` and see if it still throws an error.

Comment: Yes it does, I tried decimal

Comment: It means you may be missing a core file. Give me a minute.

Comment: navigate to the file via this path ```...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint.php``` and check if you have the required functions. search for ```public function string```

Comment: Yes thank you, I accidentally replace the "string" type with "decimalstring" type.

Comment: Also avoid editing laravel core files

Comment: never edit anything in vendor folder.  It will be replaced next time you run composer upgrade or install, and then your app is broken and you won't remember why

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a library/files are missing. Run `composer require doctrine/dbal` and it will add the library if it's missing.